# jQuery cycle: how is wrapper width calculated?

Tags: jquery, css

I've implemented a cycle effect like the one seen [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html). In that demo the plugin adds the following inline css on the div that contains the sliding elements:

```
overflow: hidden; position: relative;
```

On my page however it adds this css:

```
overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 302px; height: 414px;
```

Because of this, part of the content of the sliding div is obscured / invisible. How does the plugin calculate this width of 302px and how can I alter it?

My test page can be seen [here](http://www.iprlondon.com/) and the issue is that the right gray border when mouseovering the center images does not appear in some browsers. It is obscured by the #slider div. I'm making ongoing changes to this so things may look a little weird

EDIT: I managed to fix it with the JS below but am still interested in getting this question answered

```
$("#slider").css('width', "420px");
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem.  If you just need a fixed width, add the following options to the cycle() call:

```
width:530,
fit:true
```